# Reasonable Tutoring Rate

Tags: tutoring

I am a graduate student considering tutoring another student in a challenging graduate level statistics course.  What is a reasonable hourly rate to charge?  This is a public university in the United States.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Any rate you can get the student you're tutoring to agree to is a fair hourly rate.  I've charged up to $80/hr for tutoring students in the US in the past (usually that rate paid for by a small group).  I've also tutored friends for just dinner or some beers.  Just make sure both parties agree, probably best over email or something with a paper trail.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, under such a circumstance, I think it is fair to charge at least $30/hour. Going over this really depends on the student's ability to pay higher rates.